# How to display image in datagrid StackPanel based on binding value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have requirement to display image as a separate row based on the binding value.
Datagrid code as follows.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="OrderId : "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderId}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="OrderTime : "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderTime}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="OrderStatus : "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderStatus}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

I would like to add one more StackPanel with `<Image Source=""/>`. Source path will be based on `{Binding OrderStatus}` from above grid. If OrderStatus value is "New" I want to display new.png. If OrderStatus value is "Old" I want to display old.png and so on...

Can any one help me out.

Comment: Use Binding and a Converter.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [DataTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger(v=vs.110).aspx). The link also has a good example.

Comment: Your help was useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="OrderId : "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderId}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="OrderTime : "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderTime}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="OrderStatus : "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderStatus}"/>
                                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Width="250px" Height="50px" Margin="3,0">
                                      <Image.Style>
                                       <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                       <Style.Triggers>
                                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OrderStatus}" Value="New">
                                       <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/New.png"/>
                                       </DataTrigger>
                                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OrderStatus}" Value="Old">
                                      <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/Old.png"/>
                                      </DataTrigger>
                                      </Style.Triggers>
                                     </Style>
                                    </Image.Style>
                                   </Image>
                               </StackPanel>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```